# Regular expression word1.word2 -> word2 in Eclipse find-replace dialog

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to do some string substitution in eclipse using a find-replace dialog (Ctr-F) and I am not even sure it's possible to do in a single operation...

Suppose I am editing a text file that among other things, contain a list of pairs of words (the words in the pair are separated by a dot, the pairs are separated by a comma) such as

```
{word1.word2,word3.word4,wordn.wordm,...}
```

I want to find all the strings that match this pattern and replace it with
a list of all the second word in the pairs, e.g

```
{word2,word4,wordm,...}
```

Is that possible to do with a single find-replace operation, and if so, what would be the find and replace expressions?

Obviously in the find-replace dialog I would check the regular expression and the replace all check boxes

Comment: Are the pair of word enclosed in the flower brackets(**{}**)?If so is it occurs in a single line or extends to multi line?

Comment: No, a set of pairs is enclosed in the curly braces. A pair example is the string "word1.word2". Each set is on a single line (but why does that matter?)

Answer (score 1):

It's not bullet-proof, but try this:

```
Search: (?<=\{|,)\w+\.(?=\w+(,|\}))
Replace: <blank>
```

That's assuming eclipse supports look arounds, which it doesn't when replacing due to a [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481). Converting the look arounds to captures and simply putting the captured text back, this works (tested):

```
Search: (\{|,)\w+\.(\w+(,|\}))
Replace: $1$2
```

Comment: The Search string seems to be finding the right things. But, no matter what i enter for Replace string, the replacement doesn't happen. When i click on Find - seems to find the next <first word> but clicking Replace does not do anything. Find-Replace All does nothing as well

Comment: Are the files you're looking at source files for imported libraries or resource files shipped in a jar, and therefore not editable?

Comment: I was trying the above in a normal editable source file. Perhaps it's a bug in Eclipse

Comment: looks like a bug in Eclipse. If I do Replace All it responds with "<n> matches replaced", where n is correct, but there is no change in the file. So i'll up-tick your answer even though it doesn't work at the moment, but still looking for someone to suggest a working solution or workaround

Comment: I tried it myself and got exactly the same. I did some digging and your suspicion was correct - it's a [known bug with eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481) where it won't replace if the regex uses look arounds. Luckily, this can be solved without using look arounds by converting the look arounds into captures and replacing them. See edit

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for that. Search for `([^{.,]+)\.([^{.,]+)` and then use `\2` or `$2` as the replace pattern.

The `()` around parts of a regexp tell it to remember this part as a group. You can then access each group by number. `$0` is a special group which is equal to the whole matched input.

If you nest groups, then just count the `(` to find the number to use:

```
a((1)?(2)?)b
```

Group 1: `1?2?`
Group 2: `1?`
Group 3: `2?`

Comment: But, for this, don't you have to know the number of groups and explicitly state each of the $n in the replace string? since i don't know how many there are, it can't be done this way. If I'm wrong, please specify the two strings to the above replacement (the find and replace strings)

Comment: @inor: The regexp works because you have pairs of words separated by `,`. My regexp matches one of those pairs in the whole long list and then keeps the second word. Apply it several times to get rid of all the first words or use `Replace All`.

Comment: i need this to work in the pattern i  specified (braces and everything). if i do Replace All it will replace word pairs that are outside braces... i'm looking for a reg exp's that i can use Replace All but it will only do it for the pattern i specified

Comment: @inor: Select the part of the document where you want this to happen. The find dialog has an option to limit its operation to the current selection. If you can't do that, then you need to write a program to do it; simple regexps are not powerful enough for this use case.

Comment: thanks but i don't want to select each of the patterns and do the find-replace. i want to do it once for the whole file. Seems like the answer @Bohemian has given above has the right reg expr'n but for some reason the replace does not work...